# Aggregated column use in Hive Query

Tags: hadoop, hive

My hive table (tab1) structure:

```
people_id,time_spent,group_type
1,234,a
2,540,b
1,332,a
2,112,b
```

Below is the query i am trying to execute but getting error ("Not yet supported place for UDAF 'sum'"):

```
select people_id, sum(case when group_type='a' then time_spent else 0 end) as a_time, sum(pow(a_time,2)) as s_sq_a_time,sum(case when group_type='b' then time_spent else 0 end) as b_time, sum(pow(b_time,2)) as s_sq_b_time from tab1 group by people_id;
```

Is it possible to refer aggregated column from same select statement in Hive?
I have also referred below link but it didnt work:
http://grokbase.com/t/hive/user/095tpdkrgz/built-in-aggregate-function-standard-deviation#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a derived table to refer to `a_time` and `b_time`

```
select a_time, b_time,
pow(a_time,2) as s_sq_a_time,
pow(b_time,2) as s_sq_b_time
from (
    select people_id,
    sum(case when group_type='a' then time_spent else 0 end) as a_time,
    sum(case when group_type='b' then time_spent else 0 end) as b_time 
    from tab1 group by people_id
) t1
```

Comment: thanks for your reponse...if you look at my query i am using sum in pow function like "sum(pow(a_time,2)) as s_sq_a_time" ....is it possible to achieve in hive? appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3252809 I don't think it's possible to refer to an alias in the same select

Answer (score 1):

Set an alias for the table name and use the table alias when accessing the columns.

E.g.

```
select startstation, count(tripid) as a
from 201508_trip_data as t
group by t.startstation
```

Note 't' is the alias for the table and I've used t.startstation to access the

Comment: @Wesrock how does this answer the question? op wants to aggregate the result of an aggregate - i.e. `sum(pow(...))` - this just does a simple `count`